# Nuxt/Vue reactive body attributes

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I want to add the class `menu-opened` on the `body` tag when I click on the menu burger div.

**My div**

```
<div v-on:click="openMenu"></div>
```

**The openMenu method**

```
methods: {
     openMenu() {
       console.log('open menu launch')
       this.$store.dispatch('menu/setMenu', true)
     }
    }
```

**My store**

```
state = {
    isMenuOpen: false
}

actions = {
    setMenu({ commit }, value) {
      commit('SET_MENU_OPEN_STATUS', value)
    }
}

mutations= {
    SET_MENU_OPEN_STATUS(state, newState){
        state.isMenuOpen = newState
    }
}
```

On my template, i got this code to add the class on the body based on the state of the isMenuOpen value :

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
           menuState: this.$store.state.isMenuOpen
        }
    },
    head () {
      return {
        bodyAttrs: {
          class: this.menuState ? 'menu-opened' : ''
        }
      }
    }
}
```

> My store is working well, the value change when I click on my div, but it's not adding the class, like if the head function is not reactive...

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you show the code / template that includes `<body>`?

Comment: This is the nuxt HTML model here : https://fr.nuxtjs.org/guide/views/#document

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## In Nuxt

This is because the head method is only called once on initial page load. If you would like to update the values you can, but you will need to call the `head()` function again.

You could do this with a `watcher` or you could call it from your store.

A quick and kind of dirty way would be with a combination of computed properties and a watcher..

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
           menuState: this.$store.state.isMenuOpen
        }
    },
    head () {
      return {
        bodyAttrs: {
          class: this.isMenuOpen ? 'menu-opened' : ''
        }
      }
    },
   computed: {
     isMenuOpen () {
       return this.$store.state.isMenuOpen
     }
   },
   watch: {
     isMenuOpen () {
       this.head()
     }
   }
}
```

## In Vue

You need to watch on events like `mounted` or `beforeDestroy` described there

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html

and use pure js to modify dom like

```
const bodyElement = document.querySelector('body')
bodyElement.classList.add('a');
bodyElement.classList.remove('b');
bodyElement.classList.toggle('c');
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: If i place this on a layout, i get `this.head is not a function` as an error and rendering fails

Comment: Calling `this.head()` has no effect.

Comment: This is great answer, but works only in nuxt. In question there is nuxt/vue, so if it is disliked then only because of users of pure vue.

Comment: It's an old question , but i managed to do this in Nuxt like your answer, i'm updating the values in the store and use the store values in default.vue to update the bodyAttrs... i just have one issue , there is a latency when updating the classes , i can see that the values are updating in DevTools but the classes are not updating at the same time ... i use the same values from the store on three places to update the classes ... i created a gif for better understanding... anyone has a clue what am i doing wrong ... https://gifyu.com/image/FjPD

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

**My div**

```
<div v-on:click="openMenu" ref="myDiv"></div>
```

**The openMenu method**

```
methods: {
     openMenu() {
       console.log('open menu launch')
       this.$refs.myDiv.closest('body').classList.add("menu-opened")
     }
    }
```

And then you need to implement similar functionality for the close-menu button, only using:

```
this.$refs.myDiv.closest('body').classList.remove("menu-opened")
```